# Pyaudio modify paint16 data

Tags: pyaudio

I have this code that is ubiquitous on this site and elsewhere where you can stream data from your Microphone to speaker. Streaming the data as it is works fine, but I'd like modify the data before sending it out.

```
import pyaudio
import sys

CHUNK = 1024
WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_INPUT_FILENAME = "Microphone_sound.wav"  # Name of wave file
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "Speaker_sound.wav"  # Name of wave file
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
FORMAT_OUT = pyaudio.paFloat32
SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)

if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    CHANNELS = 1

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

in_frames = []
out_frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    # print(i)
    try:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        in_frames.append(data)
        data = data*SHORT_NORMALIZE
        out_frames.append(data)
        stream.write(data, CHUNK)
    except:
        pass

# in_frames = sound data of Microphone
in_frames = b''.join(in_frames)
# decoding the microphone data
dtype = 'int16'
Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(in_frames, dtype)
mix = Mdecoded
# ensuring no value goes beyond the limits of short int
signal = np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)
# encode the data again
encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh" % (len(signal)), *list(signal))

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_INPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(encodecoded)
waveFile.close()


# out_frames = sound data of Microphone
out_frames = b''.join(out_frames)
# decoding the microphone data
dtype = 'float32'
Mdecoded_out = np.frombuffer(out_frames, dtype)
mix = Mdecoded_out
# ensuring no value goes beyond the limits of short int
signal_out = np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)
# encode the data again
encodecoded_out = wave.struct.pack("%dh" % (len(signal_out)), *list(signal_out))

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT_OUT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(encodecoded_out)
waveFile.close()


print("* done")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

What i'd like to do is simplify normalize the data ( or modify the data) before it is sent to the output.

```
    in_frames.append(data)
    data = data*SHORT_NORMALIZE
    out_frames.append(data)
```

The original data format is int16. since i have multipled with a float i saved the result as a float, but when i check the output, the output file is more of less empty. I'm not quite sure why that is. can someone point out my mistake please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Found the answer. The Mic data is in "Bytes" form. needs to be converted to Integer as shown in this [link](https://nbviewer.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb).